# It is only that last year that I've... vs It has only been that last year that I've

Tags: grammar, present-perfect-progressive

Which is correct, and if both are correct, which one is better and what would be the difference in meaning?

> It is only that last year that I've been taking it seriously.
>
> It has only been that last year that I've been taking it seriously.

**The meaning I want to convey:** *In previous year 2019, I started to take learning French seriously and I'm still taking it seriously during this year too, 2020.  However before 2019, I wasn't taking it seriously at all.*

Update : *That* in *that last year* in both of my sentences is meant as an adjective (eg. This year/that year) not as a pronoun that has to be followed by a clause with at least one verb and one subject. And I intented to use *that* because for me 2019 is like a far away object that I'm pointing at from far away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the sentences is correct.

> It is only that last year that I've been taking it seriously.

This sentence is not correct because you're using **Present Perfect Continuous** to describe an action that happened in the past (last year, in our case it's 2019) but that is not related to now (2020). To connect it to the present, use **since last year**(from the past up until now) or **during the last year** (it will be understood as from last 365 days to now).

So, for example, it can be rewritten as follows:

> It is only since last year that I've been taking it seriously.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can I add *that* to the sentence: It's only since *that* last year that I've been taking it seriously.

Comment: @Manar it depends on a context. However, `It is only since last year` already emphasises that it is *2019* when you started taking it seriously and it still continues up until now.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is correct. All you have done is to change the tense rather than the structure

> It is only that ...

What follows "that" should be a clause, and a clause should contain at least a subject and a verb. In your sentences, there is no verb following "last year."
I am not absolutely sure what you want to say, but probably either of the sentences below gets it.

> It is only during the last year that I have been taking it seriously.
>
> It has only been during the last year that I have taken it seriously.

The first is almost certainly what would be said aloud.

The second might be used in formal writing, and I personally would do so.

Comment: Why is this correct - `It has only been during the last year that I have taken it seriously.` ? *during the last year* relates to the past that is not connected to the present.  However, **Present Perfect Continuous** is used to show that an action started in the past and has continued up to the present moment.

Comment: "During" implies continuation. It does not necessarily imply disconnection with the present.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I agree that **during** implies continuation. However, it implies continuation within the **last** year. Since there's a time gap between the present time and the last year (months, days, hours etc.) **during** doesn't continue till very now. Do you agree or is there a logical fallacy in my thinking?

Comment: The problem is that you cannot force grammar and word meanings into strict conformity with logic or metaphysics. "During my time in college" does not mean that I **necessarily** am no longer in college. Whatever quantum mechanics may say, "during" may encompass a period that continues right up through that instantaneous moment that we call the present.

Comment: I admit. Both of your sentences sound a lot better than mine. But I still don't understand why "that" , here, have to be followed by a subject+verb. I just meant it as an adjective : this year/ that year.

Comment: And the reason I used *that* not *this* is because I wanted to act as if *the last year* - since it's passed and far away from now- is like an object that I'm pointing at from faraway. I'm not sure if that's really grammatically correct but that's how I thought of it.

Comment: @Manar. Ahh. You do not mean "last year," which means either the previous calendar year (as in "Last year was 2019") or today plus the preceding 364 days. If you want to talk about a past year before the previous calendar year, you do need to use "that.": "It was only during that year that I took it seriously" or "It has only been since that year that I have been taking it seriously." Those sentences do not mean the same thing. The first denies that you now take it seriously. The second affirms that you continue to take it seriously.

Comment: @JeffMorow no I actually meant last year, 2019. And I used *that* since , for me, 2019 is far away now and it's as if I'm pointing at it from far away saying: *that last year*